# When is $\text{Rank}(A+B)=\text{Rank}(A)\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> $A$ and $B$ are two square symmetric matrices, each of order $n \times n.$ Furthermore $\text{Rank}(A)=\text{Rank}(B)=n-1$. Also $A\textit 1=\textit 0$ and $B\textit 1=\textit 0$.

Let $C=A+B$.

I want to know about $\text{Rank}(C)$, specifically if $\text{Rank}(C)$ can be $n-1$. That is, under which condition $\text{Rank}(C)=\text{Rank}(A)=\text{Rank}(B)$.

I know that $\text{Rank}(C)\leq \text{Rank}(A)+\text{Rank}(B),$ but here this implies $\text{Rank}(C) \leq 2(n-1)$. This is of no help for $n\geq 2$ since $C$ being a $n×n$ matrix, $\text{Rank}(C)\leq n$ anyway.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of the null space.

Comment: @KBS Thinking of the null space, I have reached to $Rank(C) \leq n-1$. Can you tell me when it is equal to $n-1$?

Comment: What does not it mean for a matrix to have its rank equal to $n-1$? What does it mean for the null-space.

Comment: @KBS It means that the matrix has nullity $1$.

Comment: Yeah but then apply this to your problem. Do not just answer the question.

Comment: @KBS Please elaborate.

Comment: What does it mean for your null-space to be of dimension 1 for $A$, $B$ and $A+B$? Go to the definition of a null-space if necessary.

Comment: @KBS Sorry, still not clear

Comment: Then, the best solution to you for now would be to review the properties of matrices, null-spaces, etc. in your linear algebra course. This exercise only relies on basic properties.

Comment: @user587389 How did you get ${\rm Rank}( C)\le n-1$ ? In general it is not true.

Comment: Please use `\mbox{rank}`. Please separate the statement of the problem from your thoughts about it using `---`.